# Avoid null values while filtering javascript array

Tags: javascript

How can I filter for "mna" ===1 and ignore null values

```
const words = [null, null,  {"mna":1}, {"mna":2}, {"mna":1}];

    const result = words.filter(word => word.mna === 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it to the condition so you don't try to access `mna` unless it's truthy (null values are falsy so they will cause the condition to short circuit early)

```js
const words = [null, null,  {"mna":1}, {"mna":2}, {"mna":1}];

const result = words.filter(word => word && word.mna === 1);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `word && word.mna === 1` to check if `word` is defined first. The value will be filtered out if it's **falsy** (null,undefined)

```js
const words = [null, null,  {"mna":1}, {"mna":2}, {"mna":1}];
const result = words.filter(word => word && word.mna === 1);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively use

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```js
const words = [null, null,  {"mna":1}, {"mna":2}, {"mna":1}];
const result = words.filter(word => word?.mna === 1);
console.log(result);
```

Works also when the entry exists but the element is missing

```js
const words = [{
  "count": "3",
  "noMNA": true
}, {
  "count": "3",
  "mna": 1
}, {
  "count": "2",
  "mna": 2
}, {
  "count": "3",
  "mna": 1
}];
const result = words.filter(word => word?.mna === 1);
console.log(result);
```